# How do I test changes made to a repo while fixing an issue?

Tags: javascript, github, meteor, open-source

I am trying to fix an open issue in the MeteorJs repo on github. I built the development environment like the repo said and cloned the repo. I have looked at the issue and made the necessary change that may fix the issue. But how do I test that the issue has been fixed? I have made a change to the code of the MeteorJs environment but how do I check if the issue is being handled through my change. If I build the meteorJS environment normally would'nt that be built without my change in it.

In conclusion what I want to know is that if we make changes to the repos of frameworks and environments to fix issues in them, how can we test our changes as if we run the frameworks normally they won't have the changes we make.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/DEVELOPMENT.md

Comment: Does the repo include any information on how to build and use the code?  If not then I guess you'd have to contact the owner to figure out in some way how to actually use the code.  But if it does then what's stopping you from building and using the code?  Presumably you'd have to do that in order to *observe* the issue in the first place, why can't you repeat that process to validate if you still observe the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you need additional help with this please consult the Meteor forums or join the meteor community slack. It is also possible to use GitHub discussions in the Meteor repo to discuss potential missing information on how to contribute to core Meteor.